# get errorlevel in Java

Tags: java, cmd, command-prompt, exit-code, errorlevel

I write the code in Java to launch specific application via command prompt. So the code will open cmd and run the application from there. I want to get the errorlevel of the execution. I tried with

```
String errorlevel = System.getenv("errorlevel");
System.out.println(errorlevel);
```

It always returns zero either the execution is failed or not. I also tried with getProperty() and came up with the same result.
Then the other way I tried

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
int i = p.waitFor();
System.out.println("errorLevel :" + ""+ i);
```

With this, i get the exitValue but not exactly what I want since I have to close the application to retrieve the value

What I want to know is whether it is possible to get the errorlevel of commandprompt without exit/close the process manually

Thanks before

Comment: As per my understanding `errorlevel` are return codes. How do you want to get a return value **without** shutting down your application? Could you clarify?

Comment: Why do you need the indirection via command prompt? Unless you are trying to run a script, you should be able to start the application directly. But either way, you will never be able to get the exit code of a running application, if that is what you were trying to do.

Comment: The example of the command is 'runTC testCase/String_print.tc -arg " HelloWorld " . This command will execute a specific testcase file in a specific application. It can be run only from command prompt. And from cmd  I can return  the errorlevel by echo %errorlevel% either the execution is failed or not. I use Java to call each command that is set in configuration file such as file.cfg. The question will be, is it possible to get errorlevel in Java?